# ActionListener not working correctly

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

i just want to say that i am new to java and i am doing tuts to help me better understand and what not.

now i am trying to write a program that is a Instant Messenger, the first problem is the ActionListener() it is coded right as far as i know but it just dont seem to be working.

```
//constructor
public imserver (){
    super ("Justins Instant Messenger");
    userText = new JTextField();
    userText.setEditable(false);
    userText.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener(){
            public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                sendMessage(event.getActionCommaned());
                userText.setText("");
            }
        }
    );
```

any help would be great thanks,

and this is the link to the tut im using http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pr02nyPqLBU

Comment: Please define `"dont seem to be working"`.

Comment: How can the user press the [Enter] key within a field that is not editable?

Comment: in eclipse i have a red line under that line, and as for the [ENTER] key it is coded farther down in the code, this is just at the top

Comment: What kind of event you expect to trigger `ActionOerformed` code?

Comment: to be honest im not sure what that does he doesn't explain what ActionListener does

Comment: The [Enter] key is detected internally by the `JTextField` which raises the action event.  How does your "enter" code deal with this?

Comment: here is the link to the full source code so you all can see what it all does, http://tnbforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=119&t=7001 scroll down to Tutorials 38-59 (Bucky Instant Messenger) thats where i am at

Comment: What is `getActionCommaned()`?